# C - splitting command line arguments by commas

Tags: c, string, command-line, arguments, command-line-arguments

I know that when passing command arguments such as `a.out ls -l pwd cat hello.txt`  that argv[0] is `a.out`, argv[1] is `ls` and argv[2] is `-l` etc etc.

I want to pass command arguments so that they would be separated by commas rather than whitespace
so in the command `a.out ls -l, pwd, cat hello.txt`:  argv[1] would be `ls -l` and argv[2] would be `pwd` and argv[3] would be `cat hello.txt`

my current code:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i;
    char str[100] = "";
    char* token;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        strcat(strcat(str, " "),argv[i]); // stores arguments in a string
        token = strtok (argv[i], ", "); // seperates arguments  by comma 
        printf("%s\n",token);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

its output:

```
ls
-a
pwd
cat
hello.txt
```

if I did it correctly output should be:

```
ls -a
pwd
cat hello.txt
```

Comment: If you need something with spaces in it as one argument surround it with quotes. Adding commas does nothing to change how the command line is parsed before your program even sees it.

Comment: it should work with or without quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    int i;
    char str[100] = "";
    
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        strcat(strcat(str, " "), argv[i]); // stores arguments in a string
        
        if (str[strlen(str)-1] == ',') {
            str[strlen(str)-1] = '\0'; // remove comma at the end
            printf("%s\n", str);       // do something with your token
            str[0] = '\0';             // reset str buf
        }
    }
    
    printf("%s\n", str); // do something with the remaining token

    return 0;
}
```

A version without **strtok**.

Note: If your argument list does not contain any commas, you will get the list as a whole string (not separated by 'space').

Comment: it doesn't print the last argument unless I put the print statement after the loop is finished, any way I can make it so that the print statement inside the for loop prints the last argument too?

Comment: @sjw037 Well, the logic of the loop is to concatenate the arguments to a string, until a comma is detected. That is why we need the last print outside of the loop, because there is no comma at the very end. You could also check, whether you are at the last argument, if so, print the remaining token.

Answer (score 0):

your `token` variable is just an array of characters, you need a double pointer in order to store each token for each argument. something like `char [10][1000] buffer` would work up to 10 arguments.

something like this should work:

```
typedef struct{
    char rawCmd[9999];
    char *cmd;
    char *argv[9999];
} Command;

Command parsecommand(char *rawCommand, Command c){ 
    int i = 0;
    memset(c.rawCmd, 0, sizeof(c.rawCmd));
    strcat(c.rawCmd, rawCommand); // setting the whole thing to the structs rawCmd field just in case i need the whole thing
    char *ptr = strtok(rawCommand, " ");
    c.cmd = ptr; // gets the base cmd
    while (ptr != NULL)
    { // every element after the first will be an arg (if there are any!) 
        c.argv[i++] = ptr;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    c.argv[i++] = NULL;
    return c;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i, iCommandCount = 0, iExitStatus = 0;  
    char cmd[6][9999], cur[9999]; 
    Command commands[6], c; 
    memset(&cur[0], 0, sizeof(cur));
    memset(&cmd[0], 0, sizeof(cmd));

    // seperates commands 
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        if (strcmp(argv[i], ",") != 0){
            strcat(cur, argv[i]);
            strcat(cur, " ");
        }
        if (strcmp(argv[i], ",") == 0 || i + 1 == argc){
            strcat(cmd[iCommandCount++], cur); 
            memset(&cur, 0, sizeof(cur));
        }
    }

    // splits commands by comma
    for (i = 0; i < iCommandCount; i++)
    {
        commands[i] = parsecommand(cmd[i], c);
        printf("commands: %s\n", commands[i].cmd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
 a.out ls -l ,  pwd
commands: ls
commands: pwd
```

Comment: seems to work but its not printing out the who `ls -l?` just `ls`, but thats ok since it stills splits by comma which is what I pretty much wanted